# Header file in C++ different from C

Tags: c++, c, class, header

I always used C where when you have 3 files, for example: tree.c, tree.h and main.c, in the main.c I always include tree.c and in tree.c I always include tree.h. Now in C++ is this the same? Since I found some tutorials where in tree.cpp they include tree.h and in main.cpp they also include tree.h (instead of tree.cpp as in C).

Sorry if it is confusing

Comment: Besides, what is the point of including tree.h in tree.c if you have already included tree.c in the main?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in C I would include tree.h in main.h instead of tree.c. Thus nothing is different in C++.

The idea is, that the header is the facade, describing the public interface. While the c-file contains the actual implementation that should be hidden from the user. The c files can be compiled to object files or libraries while the header stays accessible.

Answer (score 9):

There is no difference in the file inclusion mechanism between c and c++.

When you include a ".c" (or .cpp for that matters) file, you are using the so called [single compilation unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Compilation_Unit) approach.

Althought there are advocates for this approach (and it has some sort of advantages as for compilation time), this is not what is generally done, and this is why the tutorials you are referring to include the .h files.

I'm not trying to get into a debate about what's the best practice, but using the single compilation unit is not easy, since scopes can become very difficult to manage. I would suggest you to only use it when it is strictly needed (if ever) and rely on including .h files as your main choice.

Answer (score 2):

You don't include source code (.c / .cpp) in other source code, you include only headers (.h / .hpp). You compile all (.c / cpp) source files to object files and link those to an executable. What you found in the C++ tutorial is correct and valid for C too.

Answer (score 0):

C++ and C are the same in this regard. You should not `#include` other C++ or C files, only header files – sorry to say, but what you do in C is not a good practice – it breaks assumptions on file scope (that effects what a file-scope `static` means, for example) and it also means you do not benefit from faster compile cycles which you get by only compiling the files that changed.